# Unable to PULL image into minikube from insecure private registry - http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

On Ubuntu 18, I installed Docker (19.03.12) from these instructions

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

And then went through these steps

- manage docker as non-root user
  https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user
- start on boot using `systemd`
  https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot

and set up a private docker registry using this

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -e REGISTRY_DELETE_ENABLED=true --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

I also added this to the `daemon.json` file

```
{ "insecure-registries" : ["my.registrydomain.lan:5000"] }
```

And restarted the docker daemon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

I checked `docker info` to make sure the setting for insecure registry was applied and I saw this at the end so it seems ok

```
 Insecure Registries:
  my.registrydomain.lan:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
```

On the same machine I start minikube (1.12.3) with this command

```
minikube start --driver=docker --memory=3000 --insecure-registry=my.registrydomain.lan:5000
```

So everything is running and fine, and I proceed to apply my deployments using `kubectl` except when I get to the pod that needs to pull the container form the local registry I get an `ErrImagePull` status. Here is part of my deployment

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: my.registrydomain.lan:5000/name:1.0.0.9
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

When I describe the pod that failed using

```
kubectl describe pod mypod-8474577f6f-bpmp2
```

I see this message

> Failed to pull image "my.registrydomain.lan:5000/name:1.0.0.9": rpc
> error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
> https://my.registrydomain.lan:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP
> response to HTTPS client

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that I am able to PUSH my images into the registry without any issues from a separate machine over http (machine is Windows 10 and I set the insecure registry option in the daemon config)

Comment: Have see the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue with exact same settings that you provided and this works just fine. Image is being pulled without any problem. I tested this with my debian 9 and fresh ubuntu installation with this settings:

```
minikube    version:    v1.12.3
docker      version:    v19.03.12
k8s         version:    v1.18.3 
ubuntu      version:    v18
```

What I`ve done what is not described in the question is to place an entry in minikube container hosts file:

```
root@minikube:/# cat /etc/hosts
...
10.128.5.6 my.registrydomain.lan
...
```

And the tag/push commands:

```
docker tag 4e2eef94cd6b my.registrydomain.lan:5000/name:1.0.0.9
docker push my.registrydomain.lan:5000/name:1.0.0.9
```

Here`s the describe from the pod:

```
  Normal   Pulling    8m19s (x5 over 10m)     kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "my.registrydomain.lan:5000/name:1.0.0.9"
```

---

As suggested in the comments already you may want to check this [github](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874) case. It goes thru couple of solution of your problem:

[First](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874#issuecomment-608685396) is to check your hosts file and update it correctly if you hosting your repository on another node. [Second](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874#issuecomment-632121888) solution is related to pushing images in to repository which turned for the user that both `insecure-registries` and `docker push` command are case sensitive. [Third](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874#issuecomment-601843187) one is to use systemd to control docker daemon.

Lastly If those would not help I would try to clear all settings, uninstall docker, clear docker configuration and start again from scratch.

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling everything, I tried again but it still didn't work so I tried the Third step you referenced, but I get an error (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) That's just an alternative way to enable insecure-registry, but I verified it was added using daemon.json.  Also I am able to push from insecure client on Windows machine as before, its just from minikube that I can't pull.  Maybe the issue is with minikube?